# If statement partially not executed with UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I use simple if statements to make some checks before data from user form will be executed. If my statement is right code will proceed with changes, if not it will give me `msgbox`

It's part that doesn't work:

```
If Me.AusAmmTubesAuslagern.Value <= Me.AusAvailTubes Or _
      Me.AusAvailTubes <> "N/A" Then
```

First part `If Me.AusAmmTubesAuslagern.Value <= Me.AusAvailTubes` works perfectly. msgbox appeared.

If I reproduce that in my statement: that my `Me.AusAvailTubes` = N/A, it doesn't work. It make those changes. It should only happen, if that field has other txt than N/A.

I tried to get that data directly from a list not from UserForm, that same problem...

All those UserForm textboxes are filled from a list with help from other macro.

Each material is stored in 2 ways. Small pcs. or big boxes. From few of them u can take those small pcs. from other only whole boxes. Thats why i wrote 2 macros, that are working with UserForm.

1st Macro remove those small pcs.
2nd only whole boxes.

I need 2 checkpoints:

Checkpoint 1: If Me.AusAmmTubesAuslagern.Value <= Me.AusAvailTubes it checks that for ex. there are 40 Tubes in one box in warehouse and user try to remove more tan 40 it will stop him with msgbox.

Checkpoint 2: That material is not in small pcs. available, you need to take whole box with you. In that case there is column in my list that has "N/A" and it will be written with other macro in that textbox `Me.AusAvailTubes` before user will be able to try to withdraw it from warehouse with macro. That textbox need to be checked and if in that textbox is "N/A" the code will give too msgbox and will stop the code

Whole code:

```
Sub Tubes()
  Dim totRows As Long, i As Long
  Dim wsTubes As Worksheet
  Dim oldVal As Integer
  Dim newVal As Integer
  Dim AusWS As Worksheet
  Dim newValAus As String
  Dim oldValAus As String

 Select Case Me.AusListe.Value

  Case Is = "E1G"
  Set wsTubes = E1G
  Set AusWS = AusE1G

  totRows = wsTubes.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

'Check to see if value exists

 If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsTubes.Range("A:A"), Me.AusCharge.Value) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "no right Charge chosen"
   Me.AusCharge.Value = ""
 Exit Sub
End If

With wsTubes
 For i = 2 To totRows
    If .Cells(i, 1) Like Me.AusCharge Then
      If Me.AusAmmTubesAuslagern.Value <= Me.AusAvailTubes Or _
      "N/A" <> Me.AusAvailTubes Then
         oldVal = .Cells(i, 14).Value
         newVal = oldVal + Me.AusAmmTubesAuslagern.Value
         wsTubes.Cells(i, 14) = newVal
       Else
        MsgBox "So viele Stücke dieser sind nich auf Lager vorhanden!"
        Exit Sub
      End If
    End If
Next
End With
```

'Rest of the code not important to that part above

```
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided.  I suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What are the data types of `Me.AusAmmTubesAuslagern.Value` and `Me.AusAvailTubes`? It looks like you're attempting to treat `Me.AusAvailTubes` as both a string and a number.

Comment: ^^^ and in this case while `Me.AusAvailTubes <> "N/A"` would evaluate to `False`, `Me.AusAmMTubesAuslagern.Value <= Me.AusAvailTubes` would evaluate to `True`.

Comment: What type of controls are `AusAvailTubes` and `AusAmmTubesAuslagern`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is mixing numbers and strings. Or, you are confusing `OR` and `AND`?

I assume than `Me.AusAmmTubesAuslagern` and `Me.AusAvailTubes` are Controls on a Userform and you want to check the input. If you carefully check your `if`-statement, you will see that is always results in `True` - except if you enter a string starting with something like "X" into `AusAmmTubesAuslagern`

For simplicity, lets assume:

```
val1: Me.AusAmmTubesAuslagern.Value
val2: Me.AusAvailTubes
cond1: v1 <= v2
cond2: v2 <> "N/A"
```

Then, your `IF`-statement results in (added the condition also with `AND`, maybe that's what you need)

```
val1    val2    cond1   cond2   cond1 OR cond2  cond1 AND cond2  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
3       2       False   True    True            False
2       3       True    True    True            True
1       "N/A"   True    False   True            False
"AA"    "N/A"   True    False   True            False
"XY"    "N/A"   False   False   False           False
```